# How to create index pattern in elastic seach programmatically

Tags: docker, elasticsearch

I have ELK stack [deployed along my application](https://%20https://www.edc4it.com/blog/docker-kibana-elasticsearch-beats-tutorial) in docker. On first run I need to setup index pattern, and select ordering field. I know that my index pattern will always be `logstash-*` and my field will be `@timestamp`.

How can I preconfigure this in docker so I do not have to do it each time?

Comment: did you get a chance to look into my answer?

Answer (score 1):

Use [Kibana create saved objects API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/saved-objects-api-create.html) to write a script and run it in a container or something like that:

```bash
kibana_endpoint=localhost
kibana_system_user_password="12345678"

curl -X POST \
    "${kibana_endpoint}:5600/api/saved_objects/index-pattern/logstash" \
    --header "kbn-xsrf: true" \
    --header "Content-Type: application/json" \
    --user "kibana_system:${kibana_system_user_password}" \
    --data \
    "
    {
        "attributes": {
            "title" : "logstash-*",
            "timeFieldName": "@timestamp"
        }
    }
    "
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [index template](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index-templates.html#create-index-templates) to define a template, and next time whenever you create an index matching the pattern name defined in your template, it will have a settings and mappings defined in the template.